# Who was the second person Emerald affected at the Yang/Mercury match?

Tags: rwby

In [RWBY v3 ch7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFf7qoIDYuQ), Emerald says: "One mind I can handle, but two is a stretch." This implies she used her semblance on 2 people.

Obviously Yang was one at end of ch6 (since most of ch7 is a flashback), to make Yang see Mercury attacking her after the match had ended. Who was the second person she used it on at that time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Further enhancing @Arcanist Lupus's answer]
She was indeed referring to the two Ambulance officers who came to carry him away. We can see in the few seconds before they get to Mercury that he's fine, but as it shifts to their view it appears as though he is injured.

[image: Image 1 - Leg is fine]
Image 1 - Leg is fine

[image: Image 2: Leg still fine]
Image 2: Leg still fine

[image: Image 3: Leg STILL fine]
Image 3: Leg STILL fine

[image: Image 4: Leg appears injured]
Image 4: Leg appears injured

Comment: In images 2 and 3 there is a slight mark on the knee where the injury is, it's just not as easy to spot.

Answer (score 3):

She was referring to the two ambulance technicians carrying Mercury out, who could possibly have seen that his legs were made of metal.

Answer (score 1):

I think she was talking about the Ambulance who see he hurt but because she was using her semblance to hide his metal leg. So they think he's actually hurt but he is not. I'm not sure why she said "Two is stretch" unless she she had stopped using her semblance for a moment since Yang already believes Mercury was attacking her then used her semblance again on the ambulance and there was two of them so it was actually three people but two diffrent times around the same time just to be clearer.

Comment: Can you explain how this differs from the existing answers?

Comment: I meant cause there were two ambulance men.